# Display variable from code file?

Tags: coding

I'm trying to change an extension's code, and I need to display some variable contents from code files (app/code/community/extension/block/file.php) in order to be able to track down the changes I make.

Is that possible? Cause using php "echo" in those files has no effect on website frontend.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this line to dump this variable to the log file or even a custom log file as below.
Mage::log($myvariable, null, 'mylog.log', true );

Answer (score 1):

Your best, most complete solution is to get yourself setup with an IDE and xdebug.  Adding echo's or writing to a log is rather long winded and clumsy in comparison.

Comment: can you give me more information about that?

Comment: Two popular IDE's are the free [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) and the paid [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) - both are good options.  You can find information about xdebug [here](http://xdebug.org/) and there are browser plugins such as [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug-with-moveable-/?src=userprofile) to make integration easier. It takes a little bit of setting up, but once done you will wonder how you ever survived without break points!

Comment: It sounds nice but right now I don't have enough time to deal with all this. Is there some easier way to debug a few things?

Comment: I know it probably looks like the hard option right now, but it is the 'right' option.  Spend a little time getting to grips with it and you will not be disappointed with the extra power it grants to debug your code.  There's no easy workaround to get it working but once you are done you will see it's not nearly as hard as it may look right now.